What does "сам друг" mean?
This is from the book РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ published by Iosif Bikerman (a Jewish general in the White Army) in 1924.

Кадетъ или лѣвый иного толка можетъ, запершись самъ другъ съ женой,
говорить: «жиды погубили Россію»

My main problem is сам друг. There is a hyphenated entry on Multitran сам-друг stated as dialectal, supposedly meaning "the two of them together". Does this mean "when he's all alone with his wife"? It might seem obvious, but as most dictionaries do not have this, I just want to check.

Can you please move the question about иного толка into a separate post? It would be easier not to mix the two. Thank you!

Also, please consider not censoring or redacting direct quotes. It's an understandable desire, but we're a language Q/A, and when discussing language, it's always better to leave the direct quotes as is, warts and all. If people are being offended by an ethnic slur in a century-old quote, it's on them. You can clarify in a footnote that you don't condone its use.  Thank you!

Let me add, in case anyone needs to know, that the stress pattern is: сам-дру́г.

The numerals like сам-друг, сам-третей, сам-десят, сам-сот etc. had two meanings:

"Times as much": twice as much, thrice as much etc. (usually, of crops yield or returns on investment)


«Подлецы! разве так вольный труд должен давать! ведь он сам-десят должен давать — да и тогда только концы с концами свести можно!» Молчат. // [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Дневник провинциала в Петербурге (1872)]
Когда у всех худой был урожай, у него родился хлеб сам-четверт; когда у других хороший был урожай, то у него приходил хлеб сам-десят и более. // [А. Н. Радищев. Путешествие из Петербурга в Москву (1779-1790)]



"To the number of": to the number of two, three, ten, etc.; "that many people of things, him/it included". Сам-друг means "him and another one", сам-третей means "him and another two", etc. When used with the instrumental, it means "together with them, totaling that many people". Сам-друг с женой means "together with his wife", сам-десят с друзьями means "he, together with his friends, to the number of ten" and so on.


Пришел он домой — отец старик помер; сынишка был по четвертому году тоже помер, горлом болел; остался Семен с женой сам-друг. // [Вс. М. Гаршин. Сигнал (1887)]
Видно, останусь опять сам-третей с Бобкой и Тузиком. // [Н. Ф. Олигер. Смертники (1911)]




These numerals are formed by adding short (predicative) forms of ordinal numerals to the pronoun сам: друг < другой, четверт < четвертый, сот < сотый etc., with the exception of трете́й (which is a dated full form, corresponding to тре́тий in the modern language, the short form being треть) That's the only construct in which short ordinals are being used at all.
All these expressions are dated, but the latter one is still occasionally being used in card games, when talking about card combinations: e.g. валет сам-третей would mean a jack and two other cards of the same suit.

сам-третей with the instrumental case of третий?

@pompey1969: see the post update

Thank you for accepting the answer! Going forward, please consider waiting a couple of days before accepting. There's always a chance that others would give better answers, and people are often reluctant to even visit questions that already have accepted answers. Thank you!
